# How to Enable TCP/IP Forwarding in Windows Vista

Tags: tcpip, port-forwarding, putty, ssh-tunnel

Is it the same as on XP? http://support.microsoft.com/?id=315236

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>I am not sure why you have tagged this question **port-forwarding** and **ssh-tunnel**.

Can you explain what is your exact target?</sup>

The XP reference you give to enable TCP/IP forwarding,
If it works on Vista (have not checked that), will
allow you to use two network cards and setup Vista as a 'routing' device between them.
Is that what you are looking for?

---

<sup>Update:

If your question was related to setting up the Vista machine as a forwarding device,

you should remove the two tags I mention above.

I suspect that to be the case and have therefore lowered focus there.</sup>